# Rails (ActiveRecord): Last select overrides previous

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to join two selects:

```
Place.select('name').select('city')
# => SELECT "places"."city" FROM "places"
```

But it *selects* only *city* column. I think that each another *select* overrides previous one. Is it possible to concatenate many *selects*?

The above code is only simple example based on my real problem. The solutions like put everything to one *select*:

```
Place.select('name, city)
```

...are useless for me, because I join it many times in many places.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Place.select('name') & Place.select('city') ?

Comment: This produces two separate queries:
Place Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `places`.`name` FROM `places`
Place Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `places`.`city` FROM `places`

Comment: I've examined your example in rails 4.2.5 console and it worked. I can chain 2, 3, 4 selects and they seem to concatenate correctly.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.0 currently. Probably I need to check what have been changed...

Answer (score 1):

**With Arel**

[Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) can be of use to achieve your objective ...

```
p = Place.arel_table
arel_select = p.project('name').project('city')

arel_select.to_sql
=> "SELECT name, city FROM \"places\"" 

Place.find_by_sql(arel_select.to_sql)
```

Works also

```
arel_select = p.project('name')
arel_select.project('city').to_sql
```

But be aware ...

```
arel_select = p.project('name').project('city').project('city')

arel_select.to_sql
=> "SELECT name, city, city FROM \"places\""
```

**With ActiveRecord**

The *[merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge)* method is able to merge the select parts too.

```
Place.select(:name).merge( Place.select(:city) )
```

Produces the following SQL

```
SELECT "places"."name", "places"."city" FROM "places"
```

Resulting relation:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Place id: nil, name: "Zoo", city: "Berlin">]>
```

Same result as above for

```
Place.select(:name).merge( Place.select(:city) ).merge(Place.select(:city) )
```

Hope this helps,

Eugen